# Downloading files in Blazor Webassembly when using navigation manager and needing to check user claims

Tags: javascript, blazor, blazor-webassembly

I have a Blazor WASM solution in which I am trying to build functionality for downloading data from a (Radzen) datagrid. I start off by calling an export service from the code of my component like so:

```
await _exportService.Export("expense-claims-admin", type, new Query()
                {
                    OrderBy = grid.Query.OrderBy,
                    Filter = grid.Query.Filter,
                    Select = "CreateDate,User.FirstName,User.LastName,Status,ExpenseRecords.Count AS NumberOfExpenseRecords,MileageRecords.Count AS NumberOfMileageRecords,TotalAmount"
                });
```

My export service then runs the following code:

```
public async Task Export(string table, string type, Query query = null)
        {
            _navigationManager.NavigateTo(query != null ? query.ToUrl($"/export/{table}/{type}") : $"/export/{table}/{type}", true);
        }
```

This calls a controller in my server project, which runs a different action depending on the request URL. For example:

```
[HttpGet("/export/expense-claims-admin/excel")]
        public IActionResult ExportExpenseClaimsToExcelAdmin()
        {
            var claimsPrincipal = User;
            var companyId = claimsPrincipal.FindFirst(c => c.Type == "companyId");

            if (companyId != null)
            {
                return ToExcel(ApplyQuery(context.expense_claims.Where(x => x.DeleteDate == null && x.CompanyId == int.Parse(companyId.Value)), Request.Query));
            }
            //TODO - Return something other than null
            return null!;
        }
```

This then calls one of two methods depending on whether I'm trying to export to Excel or CSV. Below is the ToExcel method that gets called above:

```
public FileStreamResult ToExcel(IQueryable query, string fileName = null)
        {
            var columns = GetProperties(query.ElementType);
            var stream = new MemoryStream();

            using (var document = SpreadsheetDocument.Create(stream, SpreadsheetDocumentType.Workbook))
            {
                var workbookPart = document.AddWorkbookPart();
                workbookPart.Workbook = new Workbook();

                var worksheetPart = workbookPart.AddNewPart<WorksheetPart>();
                worksheetPart.Worksheet = new Worksheet();

                var workbookStylesPart = workbookPart.AddNewPart<WorkbookStylesPart>();
                GenerateWorkbookStylesPartContent(workbookStylesPart);

                var sheets = workbookPart.Workbook.AppendChild(new Sheets());
                var sheet = new Sheet() { Id = workbookPart.GetIdOfPart(worksheetPart), SheetId = 1, Name = "Sheet1" };
                sheets.Append(sheet);

                workbookPart.Workbook.Save();

                var sheetData = worksheetPart.Worksheet.AppendChild(new SheetData());

                var headerRow = new Row();

                foreach (var column in columns)
                {
                    headerRow.Append(new Cell()
                    {
                        CellValue = new CellValue(column.Key),
                        DataType = new EnumValue<CellValues>(CellValues.String)
                    });
                }

                sheetData.AppendChild(headerRow);

                foreach (var item in query)
                {
                    var row = new Row();

                    foreach (var column in columns)
                    {
                        var value = GetValue(item, column.Key);
                        var stringValue = $"{value}".Trim();

                        var cell = new Cell();

                        var underlyingType = column.Value.IsGenericType &&
                            column.Value.GetGenericTypeDefinition() == typeof(Nullable<>) ?
                            Nullable.GetUnderlyingType(column.Value) : column.Value;

                        var typeCode = Type.GetTypeCode(underlyingType);

                        if (typeCode == TypeCode.DateTime)
                        {
                            if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(stringValue))
                            {
                                cell.CellValue = new CellValue() { Text = ((DateTime)value).ToOADate().ToString(System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture) };
                                cell.DataType = new EnumValue<CellValues>(CellValues.Number);
                                cell.StyleIndex = (UInt32Value)1U;
                            }
                        }
                        else if (typeCode == TypeCode.Boolean)
                        {
                            cell.CellValue = new CellValue(stringValue.ToLower());
                            cell.DataType = new EnumValue<CellValues>(CellValues.Boolean);
                        }
                        else if (IsNumeric(typeCode))
                        {
                            if (value != null)
                            {
                                stringValue = Convert.ToString(value, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
                            }
                            cell.CellValue = new CellValue(stringValue);
                            cell.DataType = new EnumValue<CellValues>(CellValues.Number);
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            cell.CellValue = new CellValue(stringValue);
                            cell.DataType = new EnumValue<CellValues>(CellValues.String);
                        }

                        row.Append(cell);
                    }

                    sheetData.AppendChild(row);
                }


                workbookPart.Workbook.Save();
            }

            if (stream?.Length > 0)
            {
                stream.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);
            }

            var result = new FileStreamResult(stream, "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet");
            result.FileDownloadName = (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(fileName) ? fileName : "Export") + ".xlsx";

            return result;
        }
```

The issue I'm hitting is that the claims against the User object are never populated with the information that I need to do the checks in my export controller. I know this is because I'm calling the controller with navigation manager rather than going through a httpclient request so no authorisation token is passed, but if I use httpclient instead, the file is not downloaded by the browser.

I have tried using a combination of httpclient and javascript to get the file to download (code below) but this is returning a text file rather than an xlsx or csv file and the content is just gibberish (to me anyway).

Here's the code in my service if I use httpclient instead of navigation manager:

```
public async Task Export(string table, string type, Query query = null)
        {
            var response = await _client.GetAsync(query != null ? query.ToUrl($"/export/{table}/{type}") : $"/export/{table}/{type}");
            var fileStream = await response.Content.ReadAsStreamAsync();
            using var streamRef = new DotNetStreamReference(stream: fileStream);
            await _js.InvokeVoidAsync("downloadFileFromStream", "Export", streamRef);
        }
```

and here's the javascript code I'm using to download the file:

```
async function downloadFileFromStream(fileName, contentStreamReference) {
    const arrayBuffer = await contentStreamReference.arrayBuffer();
    const blob = new Blob([arrayBuffer]);

    const url = URL.createObjectURL(blob);

    triggerFileDownload(fileName, url);

    URL.revokeObjectURL(url);
}

function triggerFileDownload(fileName, url) {
    const anchorElement = document.createElement("a");
    anchorElement.href = url;

    if (fileName) {
        anchorElement.download = fileName;
    }

    anchorElement.click();
    anchorElement.remove();
}
```

I've read that using jsinterop to do file downloads is slow and that you're also limited by file size, so it seems like the best way to get this working would be to call the controller with navigation manager, but I just can't work out how to get those user claims if I do that and I really need to check those to make sure I'm returning the right data.

Comment: One solution would be to call your API with `HttpClient` and have your API return a download link if everything is OK. Then, use the `NavigationManager` to download the file.

Comment: Thanks @Grizzlly. I've updated my question to include the ToExcel method that gets called. Are you able to advise me on how I'd update that to return a download link instead? Would my ExportExpenseClaimsToExcelAdmin method also need updating?

Comment: I was now thinking that this approach might be a bit complex... Take a look at [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/file-downloads?view=aspnetcore-6.0#download-from-a-url). Maybe this can work better. My idea was to save the excel on the server under some generated filename and return that to the client.

Comment: Hi Hannah - have you read this part of the Docs - It's not something I have done myself, so it might not be useful...? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/security/webassembly/additional-scenarios?view=aspnetcore-6.0#attach-tokens-to-outgoing-requests

Comment: @Grizzlly It took a bit of wrangling but I ended up going with your second suggestion and managed to get it working. Thank you.